# Firefox onlick event on html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

In Mozilla Firefox click on html5 video makes it pause/play by default, but not in Chrome or Safari.
And i want to disable this behavior in FF.
But it seems that FF prevent from bubbling some events on video and i cant catch clicks.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.html5video')) { 
        console.log('click');
    }       
});
```

This code will do nothing in FF.

Any suggestions to solve this? How can i track click events on html5 video tag in FF?

Should i use some kind of wrappers or...?

Comment: put a transparent div over the video and catch those clicks?

Comment: Yeah6 this sounds really great, the only problem is context menu, that now appears for transparent div instead of video :(

Answer (score 2):

In the last version of FF (64) if you remove the **controls** attribute of the video element your code works.

If you cannot remove controls you may listen, for instance, on the pause event. On pause start playing again....

```js
document.querySelector('.html5video').addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
   // don't pause....
   this.play();
})
```

```html
<video class="html5video" width="400" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```